# What do the eigenvectors of the $n$th roots of $I_n$ look like?

Tags: linear-algebra

This was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012437/eigenvectors-of-nth-root-of-identity-matrix) at math stackexchange a long time ago with no answers but some upvotes.

Let $A^n=I,$ where $A$ is $n\times n,$ and assume that $A^k\neq I,$ for all $1\leq k<n.$ Since its characteristic polynomial is $x^n-1$, the distinct $n^{th}$ roots of unity are its eigenvalues,

Thus there are a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors.

- What do they look like?
- If we assume $A$ is orthogonal, what do they look like?
- If we assume $A$ is real, can one say anything more?

Comment: 1) Just because $A^k \neq I$ for $1 \leq k < n$ doesn't imply that its charateristic polynomial is $x^n - 1$. Take, for example, $n = 6$, $A$ the block-diagonal matrix with one block each of sizes 1, 2, 3, where each is its own root of unity. 2) A polynomial equation in $A$ tells you little about the eigenvectors, because a change of basis respect the polynomial equation. So in fact, you could have any basis as the set of eigenvectors. This was discussed by Qiaochu Yuan at the linked question.

Comment: For an easier example: take $A = -I_2$.

Comment: @user44191, thanks for that clarification, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A^n=I$, $A$ is diagonalizable and eigenvalues are $n$-th roots of unity. They don't have to be all $n$-th roots of unity and they don't have to be distinct.
Your condition that $A^k\neq I$ simply means that for all $k<n$ not all
$\lambda_j^k$ are equal to $1$.

Speaking on eigenvectors, there are no restrictions: let $D$ be a diagonal matrix
whose elements are $n$-th roots of unity, and $B$ an arbitrary non-singular matrix.
Then $A=BDB^{-1}$ has the property that $A^n=I$ and eigenvectors are columns of $B$.

If $A$ is real, we have an additional property that eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs, and to conjugate eigenvalues correspond conjugate eigenvectors. Any $D$ and $B$ with these properties will give you $A$ with the required properties.

If $A$ is real and orthogonal, then we have the additional property that eigenvectors can be chosen to form an orthonormal basis. This means that $B$ above can be chosen unitary, so $A$ us unitary, and as it is real, it is orthogonal.

This is a complete description of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 5):

Over $\mathbb C$, this seems pretty easy. Just put in Jordan normal form, which is necessarily diagonal (since $A^n=I$) with eigenvalues that are $n$th roots of unity (since $A^n=I$), and the lcm of the orders of the diagonal entries equals $n$ (since $A^k\ne I$ for $1\le k<n$). Then the eigenvectors are the standard basis vectors if the diagonal entries are distinct, but there will be higher dimensional eigenspaces if there are repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: There are also the permutation matrices of order n, which get pretty exotic for composite values of n.  Gerhard "Searching For A Good Adjective" Paseman, 2019.02.14.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I'm probably missing something, but I think that a permutation matrix of exact order $n$ will have Jordan normal form as I've described, from which one can read off exactly what he eigenvectors look like. If one wants to stick to matrices over $\mathbb R$, or over $\mathbb Q$, things get more complicated. But for a single matrix over $\mathbb C$, I don't see why a permutation matrix is all that special in terms of its eigenvectors (other than there always being an all-one eigenvector with eigenvalue 1).

Comment: You are probably right.  I've been  spending time on matters related to 0-1 matrices and permutations, and think that permutation matrices can introduce one to a combinatorial perspective on this question, especially when looking at these matrices over the rational field.  Gerhard "One Is What One Thinks" Paseman, 2019.02.14.